# tengo un problema al traspasar numero a texto en javascript

Tags: javascript

este es el codigo

```
let sumandos = [prompt('dime el primer sumando'),prompt('dime el segundo sumando')];

let resultadoSuma = parseInt(sumandos[0]) + parseInt(sumandos[1]);

alert('el resultado es ' + resultadoSuma);
```

esta en una función
el problema es que cuando yo pongo de input un numero con decimales como 3.14, 2.21 y asi ya que si lo suma pero le falta poner los puntos no es muy grave pero si me gustaria solucionarlo que puedo hacer?

Comment: parseInt parsea un entero... un entero no tiene parte decimal. Así que el código está haciendo exactamente lo que le pides que haga. Simplemente, no estás usando el tipo correcto. Prueba con parseFloat, por ejemplo

Comment: okey gracias lo voy a probar

Comment: gracias era eso xd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás tratando los números como `parseInt`, tratándose de valores enteros. Cuándo quieres manejar decimales, debes utilizar el método `parseFloat`.

Por lo que, tu código quedaría así:

```
let resultadoSuma = parseFloat(sumandos[0]) + parseFloat(sumandos[1]);
```

Puedes chequear documentación haciendo click
[aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)